# Html input, always in focus

Tags: html, css

How can I keep the html input always in focus?
Using the `autofocus` attribute when creating the element helps to focus at pageload, but it does not keep the focus on the object. Is there any simple way to keep the focus there?

Comment: Forcing focus on an input element might be a very bad design idea... I'm just saying ;)

Comment: @Terry why it might be a very bad design idea?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<!-- On blur event (unfocus) refocus the input -->
<input onblur="this.focus()" autofocus /> 
<input value="Can't focus on this" />
```

Basically, you add a `blur` event (which occurs whenever the input loses focus), and in the blur event, you focus on the input. In addition, you add the `autofocus` attribute to start off focused as well.

P.S. If you are planning to use this for a website for actual people to use, from a user interface perspective, this is probably not a great idea.

Comment: Seems like a great idea for me if you mean to make a command-line website

Comment: @KiJéy That's why I visit here!

Comment: Hi, if I understand correctly is this mean that "Can't focus on this" should never be editable on mouse click? If yes, then I found this is not working as expected
Sorry, let me update , I mean this is not working on firefox

Comment: BE AWARE that keyboard navigation on the entire page will suffer because of this. So use it with caution. I'm personally using this for a messaging app where the input field always stays focused. Similar to how WhatsApp does it. It's basically a tradeoff between navigability and usability

Comment: anyone know why this trick is not working on firefox?

Answer (score 14):

For react and the like:

```
<input  type={'text'}  autoFocus={true} onBlur={({ target }) => target.focus()}/>
```

Answer (score 3):

For **FIREFOX**, Try using **setTimeOut**, it works :

My JS :

```
myFocusFunction(){
      let myInput = document.getElementById('idOfInput');
      setTimeout(function() { 
           myInput .focus(); 
      }, 100);
}
```

my Html :

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="myFocusFunction()" auto-focus >
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using the `autofocus` attribute on the HTML input to focus it on initial page load, and then disabling all mousedown events:

```
document.onmousedown = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Obviously if you need to support mouse events, you'd want a less drastic approach, but it fit my use case for a command-line emulator web app.